# VBA Help- If one cell contains a specific value AND another cell has a date ? than another cell- delete entire row

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet that has data I need to remove based on three different cells. Here is my goal:

If A1=31 AND B1 contains a date > than the date in C1, delete the entire row. I need to loop through the full data set and check each row. I have it removing the row if A1=31 and looping through the worksheet, but can't seem to add the date component.

Here is my coding. It is probably kind of messy since mostly copied and pasted. I am not an a very experienced coder and don't really care what it looks like as long as it works. I am also not working with massive datasets so speed isn't an issue.

```
Sub Remove_Future_Dates()
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long

Firstrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        '.ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    With ActiveSheet
        .Select
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Lrow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1

            With .Cells(Lrow, "A")

                If Not IsError(.Value) Then

                    If .Value = "31" Then .EntireRow.Delete
                End If
                End With

        Next Lrow

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: A1 and B2? is the date on another row?

Comment: `If .Value = "31" And .Offset(1,1) > Offset(1,2) Then`

Comment: Sorry, I just used random cells for an example. My goal is if A1=31 and the date in B2 is > C3, then delete the entire row.

Comment: A1, B2 and C3? three different rows? or all on the same row? A1, B1 and C1?

Comment: `If .Value = "31" And .Offset(,1) > Offset(,2) Then` for the same row

Comment: The B value is on the same row, but the C value is actually on another worksheet

Answer (score 0):

## Still Unclear

### This is not yet a working code!

If you are not going to run this code on different sheets you should change ActiveSheet to the index number like you did with Worksheets(2). It is preferred to use worksheet names and best to use code names though.

You will have to define the 'OtherWorksheet' name (or index) I used and adjust its column and row. Uncomment the commented parts only after you got the code working.

I make this code working, if you provide the names or the indexes of all the worksheets envolved and an exact 'series of 3' of data e.g. A1, B1 on Sheet1, worksheet(1),  Worksheet("Master") or ActiveSheet and C2 on Sheet3, Worksheet(3) or Worksheet("Slave").

```
Option Explicit

Sub Remove_Future_Dates()

    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long

'    With Application
'        CalcMode = .Calculation
'        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'        .ScreenUpdating = False
'    End With

    On Error GoTo SafeExit

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        LastRow = .Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        For Lrow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
            With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
                If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                    If .Value = "31" _
                        And .Offset(0, 1) > _
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OtherWorksheet") _
                            .Cells(Lrow + 1, "C") _
                        Then .EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
        Next Lrow
    End With

SafeExit:

'    With Application
'        CalcMode = .Calculation
'        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'        .ScreenUpdating = True
'    End With

End Sub
```